# Error On Randomizing Strings In A List C#

Tags: c#, list, random

I want to create a program that shows a random category (from the list of category I've created) with the right words in a message box whenever I click the button.

The categories is randomized when I run it but the right word that should be with the category isn't correctly placed.
[Image of Error](http://i717.photobucket.com/albums/ww176/T3ZTAM3NT/2ndSSonError_zps1a838970.jpg)

Also, I know that the program will crash once the program reaches a negative index of a category or once all of the category is shown
[Image of Error](http://i717.photobucket.com/albums/ww176/T3ZTAM3NT/3rdSSonError_zps5212cfe5.jpg)

but I can't figure out what logic to use so that it would automatically stops removing index once it has reached a negative value.

Code:

```
namespace randomCategory
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Random rand = new Random();
    List<string> categories = new List<string> { "Book Titles", "Movie Titles", "Car Parts", "Human Body Parts", "Transportations" };


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = categories;
    }

    public void selection()
    {
        // logic for setting a random category
        int index = rand.Next(categories.Count);
        var category = categories[index];


        // logic for assigning the word for a category
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show(category, "Harry Potter");
                break;
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show(category, "Summer Wars");
                break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show(category, "Bumper");
                break;
            case 3:
                MessageBox.Show(category, "Eyes");
                break;
            case 4:
                MessageBox.Show(category, "Boat");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Empty!", "!!!");
                break;
        }

        categories.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selection();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you thought about changing the `List<T>` to use either `HashSet, LinkedList or Dictionary`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm kinda new to C# and now trying to search how to use Dictionary as it is also the recommended way said by other people. I'm trying to think of ways on how to convert the code into HashSet and LinkedList.

Comment: I posted a simple example on how to convert the existing List<T> to a Dictionary<T,T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the listbox selection to reflect the random index that you selected.

Also, if there are no items in the list, you shouldn't do this. So add this code to your method:

```
if (categories.Count == 0)
    return;
```

The problem might be that, when you delete an item from the `categories` list, the index numbers no longer match up with your `switch` statement. For example, your `categories` starts out as:

```
{ "Book Titles", "Movie Titles", "Car Parts", "Human Body Parts", "Transportations" };
```

If you select any item from the list, it will match up in your switch. For example, if you randomly select 1, then your program will display "Summer Wars": a movie title.

But then you remove that item from the list. Your list now looks like this:

```
{ "Book Titles", "Car Parts", "Human Body Parts", "Transportations" };
```

So you randomly select 2, which is "Human Body Parts" because you removed an item from the list.

One way you can get around this problem is by creating another list, called `unusedCategories`. Initialize it like this:

```
List<int> unusedCategories = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Now, you select an item from that list:

```
int selectedIndex = rand.Next(unusedCategories.Count);
int index = unusedCategories[selectedIndex];
// at this point, index is the index to one of the items in your `categories` list

switch (index)
{
    ....
}

unusedCategories.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
```

And, of course, you'll change the `if` statement to:

```
if (unusedCategories.Count == 0)
    return;
```

Comment: Actually in my program the only purpose of the listbox1 is just to show the user what are the categories that will be randomizedly shown and nothing more. What I really want to happen is to make the random category to be able to have linked correctly with the right word for that category.
The if control statement worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jim Mischel! You've provided me with the codes and the important details on why the error showed up.
So, it was wrong of me to actually remove the index on the list of the category as it would result in a removal of index causing the range/count to move that will make my switch statement shift the index to a wrong assignment of indexing the category.

Comment: The solution to this as Jim said would be to create another list that will be a substitute for the removal of index on the list but will remove the selectedIndex and still keep the index so that it will randomize and coorectly making the switch condition to make the word match with the right category.
Thank you Mr. Mischel! :]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your existing List of `string` to a `Dictionary<T,T>`
one line of code can do it for you

```
var categories = new List<string> 
{ 
  "Book Titles",
  "Movie Titles",
  "Car Parts",
  "Human Body Parts",
  "Transportations" 
 };
var catDict = categories.ToDictionary(c => c);
```

Comment: I think that the way that I solved the solution is not preferable and will have limitation if I use it in another assignments and associations. I will look more into solving it to HashSets, LinkedLists and Dictionary and thanks for your help also, DJ KRAZE.